# Unable to update BitDefender 2010

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bitdefender

I installed Bitdefender 2010, but I am unable to update it. It keeps on giving me the error:

An error occured during the update (Unknown error).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I dont know the best answer yet. I switched to Bitdefender 2011 and it worked. It seems that Bitdefender 2010 has some issues with 64-bit windows.

Answer (score 1):

`Unknown error` points to a race condition or temporary misconfiguration. Rebooting may solve those.

If you want to know more about the error, you can watch the raw packets with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). wireshark also allows you to record packet capures, which can help superuser answerers or Bitdefender's support to trace the problem.

Comment: Update didnt work even after so many different tests, even those mentioned on bitdefender blog. Maybe wireshark should have helped... why didnt I think of it before!? ... Anyways I installed Bitdefender 2011 and it works fine... thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall it using the supported [Uninstaller tool](http://www.bitdefender.com/support/How-to-uninstall-BitDefender-333.html), and reinstall it (after a reboot, of course).

Comment: Thanks... maybe that would have worked but being extremely frustrated, I switched to Bitdefender 2011.

Comment: That could also work :-). Make this an answer and then you can accept it to close the question.